# How make one http-request per second in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, get, httprequest

there. I have (for example) 100 links and I need to create 100 http requests (using request module) to these resourses, but i have one restrict - no more than one request per second. Could you help can i organize this using [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) and [request](https://github.com/request/request) modules?

**UPDATE**

I provided my work code.

```
var async = require('async');
var request = require('request');
async.concat(links, function (link, callback) {
    request(link, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            callback(null, body);
        }
    });
}, function () {
    console.log(results);
});
```

Comment: How about `setInterval` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can eachSeries of async library

```
async.eachSeries(urlArray, function iterator(url, callback) {

     processurl( callback );

}, function done() {
  //...
});
```

Comment: Hi, i used the similar example. But how i can make maximum one request per second?

Comment: with this example, once first requrest completed, then an only second request will be processed. If first request takes 3 second , then second request will be start after 3 second.

Comment: But if my first request long less then than one second?

Answer (score 0):

You can use throttle function in underscore.js to rate-limit calling a function.

[underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle)